# Grouping month to date comparisons with total for month

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe (`df`) which looks like this:

```
+----------+------------+-------------+----------+----------------
|    id    |    name    |  predicted  |  actual  |  yyyy_mm_dd   |
+----------+------------+-------------+----------+----------------
|    215   |     Nir    |     100     |   200    |  2020-01-01   |
|    215   |     Nir    |     110     |   210    |  2020-01-02   |
|    200   |     Xyc    |     120     |   220    |  2020-01-01   |
|    200   |     Xyc    |     130     |   230    |  2020-01-02   |
```

The above is stripped a bit, my actual df has daily data for all of 2020, with 60 ids per day. For future dates, only the `yyyy_mm_dd`, `predicted` and `id` columns won't be `NaN`. The other columns get populated ~3 days after the day has happened.

I want to add a `payout` column. The data in this column should be 0 unless:

- Sum Month to date of `actual` >= `sum(predicted)` for the entire month.

If the above condition is met, then `payout` should be the 1% of the difference between `actual` and `predicted`

Here is an illustrated example:

```
SELECT 
    name, sum(predicted)
 FROM
     my_table
WHERE
    yyyy_mm_dd between '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31'
GROUP BY
    1
------------------------------------------------------
Nir, 50000
Xyc, 100000
```

If 'Month to date' of `actual` for January <= 50000 for Nir / 100000 for Xyc then `payout` should *always* be 0, even if `actual` >= `predicted` for that given day.

Once 'Month to date' of `actual` for January >= 50000 for Nir / 100000 for Xyc, we should mark `payout` as 1% of `actual`-`predicted` for that day.

---

I have tried keeping a running total in a new column like this:

```
new_sum = [df.actual.values[0]]
for i in range(1, len(df.index)):
    new_sum.append(new_sum[i-1]+df.actual.values[i])
df['actual_sum'] = new_sum
```

However, that didn't total didn't reset per month per company and I wasn't sure how to compare the running total (`new_sum`) to the total for the same month for the same company.

I also tried this:

```
df['inc'] = df['actual'] - df['predicted']    
df['payout'] = np.where(df['inc']>=1, (df['inc'] / 100) * 1, 0)
```

But the above doesn't make sure the month to date >= total for the month before attributing the 1%.

*Edit*: My expected output is the current df but with an additional `payout` column. This new column should match the logic described above.

Basically need to get total of predicted for the month. Then add the daily sum of `actual` as the days roll by. As we get closer to the end of the month, `actual` should start surpassing the `predicted` total for the month. Once that threshold has been passed, then the payout will be start being 1% of `actual` - `predicted`. Until that point though the payout is 0. The dataset is daily data until the end of 2020.

```
+------------+-----------+--------+------------+-------+
|  id | name | predicted | actual | yyyy_mm_dd |payout|
+------------+---------- +--------+------------+-------+
| 215 | Nir  |   100     |  200   |  2020-01-01|xxx
| 215 | Nir  |   110     |  210   |  2020-01-02|xxx
| 200 | Xyc  |   120     |  220   |  2020-01-01|xxx
| 200 | Xyc  |   130     |  230   |  2020-01-02|xxx
```

Comment: can you show your expected output?

Comment: what does x represent? from my understanding all the rows here meet your condition thus are eligible for the payout?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC,

we can use `Groupby.Transform` which allows you to run groupby aggregations without modifying the index, and to then use `np.where` to broadcast your desired result onto your target dataframe.

since you're using calendar months this is quite easy, if you're using a custom business, retail or financial calendar then you'll need to customise the solution by merging the date time with your calendar.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df["yyyy_mm_dd"] = pd.to_datetime(df["yyyy_mm_dd"])
m = df.groupby(['id',df['yyyy_mm_dd'].dt.month])['predicted','actual'].transform('sum')

df["inc"] = np.where(
    df["actual"] >= m["predicted"], (m["actual"] - m["predicted"]) * 0.01, 0
)
```

---

```
print(df)
    id          name  predicted  actual yyyy_mm_dd  inc
0  215       Nir            100     200 2020-01-01  0.0
1  215       Nir            110     210 2020-01-02  2.0
2  200       Xyc            120     220 2020-01-01  0.0
3  200       Xyc            130     230 2020-01-02  0.0
```

or

--

```
df["inc"] = np.where(
    df["actual"] >= m["predicted"], (df["actual"] - df["predicted"]) * 0.01, 0
)

print(df)

    id          name  predicted  actual yyyy_mm_dd  inc
0  215       Nir            100     200 2020-01-01  0.0
1  215       Nir            110     210 2020-01-02  1.0
2  200       Xyc            120     220 2020-01-01  0.0
3  200       Xyc            130     230 2020-01-02  0.0
```

Comment: I added expected output, I hope it makes sense.

Comment: On `2020-01-01` Nir should have 0 payout because the sum of `predicted` for Nir is 210. On `2020-01-01` Nir only had an actual of 200. On `2020-01-02` Nir passes the `200` as his `sum(actual)` is `>=200`. Since this is the case, the payout for Nir on this day should be 1% of `actual`-`predicted`.

Comment: it still doesn't look correct as the total `predicted` for `Xyc` is 250. On `2020-01-01` the payout is correct, as the `actual` to date is less than the sum of `predicted`, however the `2020-01-02` should have a payout as `220+230` = 450 so we have no passed the sum of predicted for Xyc.

Comment: @Someguywhocodes correct is arbitary until you provide a [mcve] you really need to fill out your `payout` column once you do i'll edit my answer

Comment: I realise this question may have been a bit ambiguous so I submitted a new one this morning with a better example and expected output. Here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59875430/efficiently-compare-running-total-for-month-to-total-for-month?noredirect=1#comment105882776_59875430. I hope this clears up the confusion