# Efficiently compare running total for month to total for month

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe (`df`). It contains `predicted` daily data from a model, up until the end of 2020. As each day passes in the year, `actual` and `id` data is added to the row. There are multiple names for each day

```
+------+-----+-----------+--------+------------+
| NAME | ID  | PREDICTED | ACTUAL | YYYY_MM_DD |
+------+-----+-----------+--------+------------+
| Nir  | 215 | 100       | 400    | 2020-01-01 |
| Nir  | 215 | 200       | 400    | 2020-01-02 |
| Nir  | 215 | 100       | 400    | 2020-01-03 |
| Nir  | 215 | 200       | 400    | 2020-01-04 |
| Nir  | 215 | 100       | 400    | 2020-01-05 |
| Nir  | 215 | 200       | 400    | 2020-01-06 |
| Nir  | 215 | 100       | 400    | 2020-01-07 |
| Nir  | 215 | 200       | 400    | 2020-01-08 |
| Nir  | 215 | 100       | 400    | 2020-01-09 |
| Nir  | 215 | 200       | 400    | 2020-01-10 |
| Nir  | 215 | 100       | 400    | 2020-01-11 |
| Nir  | 215 | 200       | 400    | 2020-01-12 |
| Nir  | 215 | 100       | 400    | 2020-01-13 |
| Nir  | 215 | 200       | 400    | 2020-01-14 |
| Nir  | 215 | 100       | 400    | 2020-01-15 |
| Nir  | 215 | 200       | 400    | 2020-01-16 |
| Nir  | 215 | 100       | 400    | 2020-01-17 |
| Nir  | 215 | 200       | 400    | 2020-01-18 |
| Nir  | 215 | 100       | 400    | 2020-01-19 |
| Nir  | 215 | 200       | 400    | 2020-01-20 |
| Nir  | 215 | 100       | 400    | 2020-01-21 |
| Nir  | 215 | 200       | 400    | 2020-01-22 |
| Nir  | 215 | 100       | 400    | 2020-01-23 |
| Nir  | Nan | 100       | Nan    | 2020-01-24 |
| Nir  | Nan | 100       | Nan    | 2020-01-25 |
| Nir  | Nan | 100       | Nan    | 2020-01-26 |
| Nir  | Nan | 100       | Nan    | 2020-01-27 |
| Nir  | Nan | 100       | Nan    | 2020-01-28 |
| Nir  | Nan | 100       | Nan    | 2020-01-29 |
| Nir  | Nan | 100       | Nan    | 2020-01-30 |
| Nir  | Nan | 100       | Nan    | 2020-01-31 |
| Xyc  | 40  | 800       | 500    | 2020-01-01 |
| Xyc  | 40  | 100       | 500    | 2020-01-02 |
| Xyc  | 40  | 100       | 500    | 2020-01-03 |
| Xyc  | 40  | 100       | 500    | 2020-01-04 |
| ...  | ... | ...       | ...    | ...        |
| ...  | ... | ...       | ...    | ...        |
+------+-----+-----------+--------+------------+
```

I want to add an additional column named `payout`. The `payout` should be 0 unless the sum of `actual`, month to date has passed the sum of `predicted`.

I.e., for `Nir`, we can see the sum of `predicted` is `4200`. So the `payout` should be 0 until the sum of `actual` passes 4200. Once that threshold is passed, then the `payout` should be 1% of `actual-predicted`. With the above data, the output would look like this:

```
+------+-----+-----------+--------+---------------+--------+------------+
| NAME | ID  | PREDICTED | ACTUAL | MONTH_TO_DATE | PAYOUT | YYYY_MM_DD |
+------+-----+-----------+--------+---------------+--------+------------+
| Nir  | 215 | 100       | 400    | 400           | 0      | 2020-01-01 |
| Nir  | 215 | 200       | 400    | 800           | 0      | 2020-01-02 |
| Nir  | 215 | 100       | 400    | 1200          | 0      | 2020-01-03 |
| Nir  | 215 | 200       | 400    | 1600          | 0      | 2020-01-04 |
| Nir  | 215 | 100       | 400    | 2000          | 0      | 2020-01-05 |
| Nir  | 215 | 200       | 400    | 2400          | 0      | 2020-01-06 |
| Nir  | 215 | 100       | 400    | 2800          | 0      | 2020-01-07 |
| Nir  | 215 | 200       | 400    | 3200          | 0      | 2020-01-08 |
| Nir  | 215 | 100       | 400    | 3600          | 0      | 2020-01-09 |
| Nir  | 215 | 200       | 400    | 4000          | 0      | 2020-01-10 |
| Nir  | 215 | 100       | 400    | 4400          | 3      | 2020-01-11 |
| Nir  | 215 | 200       | 400    | ...           | 2      | 2020-01-12 |
| Nir  | 215 | 100       | 400    | ...           | 3      | 2020-01-13 |
| Nir  | 215 | 200       | 400    | ...           | 2      | 2020-01-14 |
| Nir  | 215 | 100       | 400    | ...           | 3      | 2020-01-15 |
| Nir  | 215 | 200       | 400    | ...           | 2      | 2020-01-16 |
| Nir  | 215 | 100       | 400    | ...           | 3      | 2020-01-17 |
| Nir  | 215 | 200       | 400    | ...           | 2      | 2020-01-18 |
| Nir  | 215 | 100       | 400    | ...           | 3      | 2020-01-19 |
| Nir  | 215 | 200       | 400    | ...           | 2      | 2020-01-20 |
| Nir  | 215 | 100       | 400    | ...           | 3      | 2020-01-21 |
| Nir  | 215 | 200       | 400    | ...           | 2      | 2020-01-22 |
| Nir  | 215 | 100       | 400    | ...           | 3      | 2020-01-23 |
| Nir  | Nan | 100       | Nan    |               |        | 2020-01-24 |
| Nir  | Nan | 100       | Nan    |               |        | 2020-01-25 |
| Nir  | Nan | 100       | Nan    |               |        | 2020-01-26 |
| Nir  | Nan | 100       | Nan    |               |        | 2020-01-27 |
| Nir  | Nan | 100       | Nan    |               |        | 2020-01-28 |
| Nir  | Nan | 100       | Nan    |               |        | 2020-01-29 |
| Nir  | Nan | 100       | Nan    |               |        | 2020-01-30 |
| Nir  | Nan | 100       | Nan    |               |        | 2020-01-31 |
| Xyc  | 40  | 800       | 500    | 500           | 0      | 2020-01-01 |
| Xyc  | 40  | 100       | 500    | 1000          | 0      | 2020-01-02 |
| Xyc  | 40  | 100       | 500    | 1500          | 4      | 2020-01-03 |
| Xyc  | 40  | 100       | 500    | 2000          | 4      | 2020-01-04 |
| ...  | ... | ...       | ...    |               |        | ...        |
| ...  | ... | ...       | ...    |               |        | ...        |
+------+-----+-----------+--------+---------------+--------+------------+
```

In the above output, `Xyc` has a total predicted 2000, so `payout` should be 0 until the sum of `actual` passes 2000 also. In the real dataframe, there is daily data for ~70 `name`s, so I feel like a grouping may be needed.

---

I've tried:

```
new_sum = [df.actual.values[0]] for i in range(1, len(df.index)): 
    new_sum.append(new_sum[i-1]+df.actual.values[i]) 
df['actual_sum'] = new_sum
```

However, that simply gave me a running total of `actual`. I also tried this:

```
df['inc'] = df['actual'] - df['predicted'] df['payout'] = np.where(df['inc']>=1, (df['inc'] / 100) * 1, 0)
```

But the above doesn't make sure the month to date >= total for the month before attributing the 1%.

Comment: I don't see sum of predicted = 4200. Were this value is coming from? If payout should be 1% of actual-predicted then payout values need to by 3,2,3,2 ..

Comment: If you sum the daily values for `predicted`  for Nir during January, you'll get 4200. Ah yes, you are correct that it should be 3,2,3,2. I'll make an edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First You need to remove NaN rows from data.

Here You go:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Nir','Nir','Nir','Nir','Xyc','Xyc','Xyc'],'PREDICTED':[100,200,100,200,100,200,300],
                   'ACTUAL':[400,400,400,400,500,500,500],
                   'YYYY_MM_DD':['2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-01-04','2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03']})


def calculate(item):
    # select name
    data = df[df['Name'] == item]
    # calculate sum
    sum = data['PREDICTED'].sum()

    # remove NaN rows
    data = data.dropna()

    # calculate and insert  month to date column values
    month_to_date = []
    value = 0
    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        value += row['ACTUAL']
        month_to_date.append(value)

    data.insert(3, "MONTH_TO_DATE", month_to_date, True)

    # calculate and instert payout values
    conditions = [
        (data['MONTH_TO_DATE'] < sum),
        (data['MONTH_TO_DATE'] >= sum)
    ]
    choices = [0, ((data['ACTUAL'] - data['PREDICTED'])/100).astype(int)]
    data.insert(5, "PAYOUT", np.select(conditions, choices), True)

    return data


# collect results
results = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name','PREDICTED','ACTUAL','MONTH_TO_DATE','YYYY_MM_DD','PAYOUT'])

for item in df['Name'].unique():
    df2 = calculate(item)
    results = results.append(df2)
```

Result:

```
  Name PREDICTED ACTUAL MONTH_TO_DATE  YYYY_MM_DD PAYOUT
0  Nir       100    400           400  2020-01-01      0
1  Nir       200    400           800  2020-01-02      2
2  Nir       100    400          1200  2020-01-03      3
3  Nir       200    400          1600  2020-01-04      2
4  Xyc       100    500           500  2020-01-01      0
5  Xyc       200    500          1000  2020-01-02      3
6  Xyc       300    500          1500  2020-01-03      2
```

Comment: If I remove the rows with `NaN` then we will lose the `predicted` values for the days which have not happened yet i.e. all rows in the future. Doing this means the sum of `predicted` will be incorrect as it won't have the full month of predicted data due to use removing rows with `NaN`. Could we get the same output while maintaining these rows?

Comment: @Someguywhocodes simply remove NaN rows after sum is calculated. Code updated.

Comment: I've tested this with some real data and it seems to work, thank you very much! As I don't have `actual` data in February yet, I was wondering will this solution work as we enter a new month? I.e. `month_to_date`  will reset for each month and company?

Comment: @Someguywhocodes this will work but as you add new month then you need to create additional loop that will filter data for each month as is done for each `Name`

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. How would it looks like with a second loop also appending to `results`? This `df` will be written to a table and updated daily. So once we roll into February, I want to retain all the `month_to_date` and `payout` values for January but also reset the count for `February` as each `name` will have a new `sum(predicted)` for the next month. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Someguywhocodes solution is in previous comment. In place where is name selected `data = df[df['Name'] == item]` you need to select `Name` and `Month`, all the rest will by unchanged.

Comment: I tried like this `data = df[df['name', 'yyyy_mm_dd'] == item]` but run into KeyError: ('name', 'yyyy_mm_dd').

Comment: @Someguywhocodes You need first to convert string into datetime format, then filter by timestamp Month: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html

Comment: Could you add it to the solution? As when my `df` *isn't* limited to one month, the solution no longer works. I think this is because the solution will do `sum(predicted)` over all months (i.e. one year) and as such the `month_to_date` within January never passes this sum as it's comparing a month_to_date to a year. This results in the `payout` being 0 despite `month_to_date` >= `sum(predicted)` for January. I hope I explained that issue clearly, it's hard for me to explain. Sorry about that!